# Detect a new network connection (linux-server) and it's status in java

Tags: java, linux, networking

Is there any way that java can detect that I have just plugged in a wired-network, and monitor it's bandwith? (I'm using linux, if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity and without using native code, you could try to using [java.net.NetworkInterface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) with polling, so every X seconds you trigger a network interface enumeration in order to see if there are new interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the program

```
/sbin/ip monitor
```

And monitor its output using a pipe or whatever.

It will tell you when

- New network interfaces are configured
- Network interfaces go up and down because the network becomes ready / not ready (this typically works by detecting an ethernet carrier or wifi access point)

The output is somewhat confusing but should be parseable.