# Will binding the server to localhost not require its reset after network change?

Tags: java, android, localhost, lan

I am developing an application on android which automatically swaps LAN networks, and I have a server which should listen on some port for connections. Will binding its address to localhost save me from the trouble of reseting the server and starting it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you are asking if binding to localhost saves your application from needed to rebind to serve on a new interface that just became available.

The short answer is no.  Binding to `localhost` only means you are binding to the loopback interface.  If a network change happens (like a wifi connection comes or goes) the loopback interface is not affected and you will have to rebind to get the new interface.

See here for some ideas: [Detect a new network connection (linux-server) and it's status in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785752/detect-a-new-network-connection-linux-server-and-its-status-in-java)

I guess you need to poll [NetworkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) every so often to see if there is a new interface.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost will be available even at network change, and should make no problem for you. Many services and applications are using it for inter-process communication (such as media player) and it is safe.